# Edit number listing of algorithm to letters

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmicx

```
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Algorithm1}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\State $X\sim f$ \\

... 

\State $X\sim g$ \\

...

\State $X\sim z$\\


\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

But i want it so that the dots after step 1 and 3 have no numbers next to it, but they always seem to automatically insert it as step 2 and 4 etc...

Further, I would like to change step 3 to step j and step 5 to step k but I cannot see how to change the numbers to letters.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please don’t post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The command `\Statex` generates a line without number.

  ```
  \State  $X\sim f$
  \Statex \dots
  \State  $X\sim g$
  \Statex \dots 
  \State  $X\sim z$
  ```
- To number the lines non-consecutively, set the counter `ALG@line` to a value one less than the number of the next line.

  ```
  \State $X\sim f$ % line number 1
  \setcounter{ALG@line}{9}
  \State $X\sim g$ % line number 10
  ```
- The arabic numbering is hard-wired in the package. To modify it, we have to replace `\arabic` in the right place by a generic command that we then can redefine to whatever we need.

  ```
  \usepackage{algorithmicx}
  \usepackage{xpatch}
  \makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd\ALG@step{\arabic{ALG@line}}{\fmtlinenumber{ALG@line}}{}{}
  \makeatother 
  \let\fmtlinenumber\arabic % by default, line numbers are arabic numbers
  \newcommand\mathalph[1]{$\alph{#1}$} % typeset counter in math italic
  ```

  As soon as we want to use letters as labels, we can execute

  ```
  \let\fmtlinenumber\mathalph
  ```

  To switch back, we can limit the effect of the switch by braces (see below in the complete code) or by executing

  ```
  \let\fmtlinenumber\arabic
  ```

Here is the complete code and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\ALG@step{\arabic{ALG@line}}{\fmtlinenumber{ALG@line}}{}{}
\makeatother 
\let\fmtlinenumber\arabic % by default, line numbers are arabic numbers
\newcommand\mathalph[1]{$\alph{#1}$} % typeset counter in math italic
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State  $X\sim f$
  \Statex \dots
  \setcounter{ALG@line}{9}% j is the tenth letter
  {\let\fmtlinenumber\mathalph % switch to alphabetic labels
  \State  $X\sim g$
  \Statex \dots 
  \State  $X\sim z$
  }% switch back to arabic; not necessary if there are no further lines
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]